# How to make an iPad specific media query ignore other tablet specific queries

Tags: android, html, ios, css, ipad

I know how to make a media query to apply a specific stylesheet to the iPad.

`<link media="screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style-ipad.css"/>`

However I don't want it to pull in the styling I have made for android tablets

`<link media="screen and (max-width: 892px) and (min-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style-medium-tablet.css"/>`

The only problem with this second query is it applies that to the iPad as well as other medium tablets.

So I am wondering if there is a way to apply css specifically to the iPad, and then use a negation of that query to keep the medium tablet css from being applied to the iPad?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have an ipad specific stylesheet in the first place?

Comment: Because the text is more readable on the iPad. It allows for a bit smaller text and different positioning.  The android tablets smash elements together unless I use a specific styling on it.  However the iPad doesn't need it and so we want it to look more like the desktop version. That iPad specific stylesheet has only three different rules in it to override the desktop styling

Comment: You're making assumptions.  The Android tablet I use most of the time has a higher DPI and resolution than an iPad (although the user agent will tell you it's an iPad since too many websites seem myopic to Android) and my other "ordinary" tablet has never "smashed elements together".  What elements are you displaying?

Comment: It just had a smaller display. I didn't make any assumptions, I am talking about Android tablets that have a smaller display than the iPad.  I have one that I have been testing the site on and based on the styling it "smashes elements together" not because of the nature of the device, but because of the styling its using.  I just wanted to find out if there was a way without using Javascript to tell it not to apply the second media query if we were on an iPad.